# Can a return statement be formatted like a printf?

Tags: java, return, printf

I am new to java, so please be patient with me if this is a "stupid" question. Is there a way to format a return statement similar to printf("%d", a)? Here's a snippet of my code thus far.

```
    public static int numUnique(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a==b && a==c) {
            System.out.println("No unique numbers.");
        } else if (a==b && a!=c) {
            System.out.printf("%d%d", a, c);
        } else if (a==c && a!=b) {
            System.out.printf("%d%d", c, b);
        } else if (b==c && b!=a) {
            System.out.printf("%d%d", b, a);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d%d%d", a, b, c);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that there needs to be a return statement in there for correct syntax, and I would like to use returns similarly to the printf being used "in theory" in my code. Thanks!

Jason

Comment: but shouldn't this method be returning an int...?

Comment: An 'int' doesn't have a format or even a representation; it's just a number. As @DavidWallace suggests, you could return a String instead.

Answer (score 8):

If you're after a method that returns a `String`, you could use the `String.format` method, which takes the same arguments as `System.out.printf`.  So the code of your question would look like this.

Note that I've introduced some spaces to stop your integers running together, and looking like a single number.

```
public static String numUnique(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a==b && a==c) {
         return "No unique numbers.";
    } else if (a==b && a!=c) {
        return String.format("%d %d", a, c);
    } else if (a==c && a!=b) {
        return String.format("%d %d", c, b);
    } else if (b==c && b!=a) {
        return String.format("%d %d", b, a);
    } else {
        return String.format("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This helps things make a lot more sense. Truthfully, your version works much better since I do not need to return a value of integer type vs string specifically.

Comment: There's a shorter way to achieve something very similar.  You could just do something like `return new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a,b,c)).toString();` without all the `if/else` stuff.  It's not exactly the same as what you're printing here, but it's close.  I didn't post it as an answer, because it doesn't actually answer your question, even though it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

With a `return` statement, you're **giving back** data.  How the program (or user) deals with that data isn't quite the concern of the method.

With a format operation, you're **representing** data.  So long as you have the right data, you can represent it in any way you like.

So, strictly speaking, it's not possible to do that, not unless you wanted to use `String.format` in such a manner that another answer has suggested.

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually helped me fix some wrongful beliefs about these types of statements.